# MySQL: Insert if this ip dont have any records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I use:

```
INSERT INTO `rating` (`name`, `user`, `rating`, `section`, `ip`)
VALUES ('$name', '{$_SESSION['user']}', '$rate', '$section',
        '{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}');";
```

I would like to add an if condition in the IF statement so that.

```
IF SELECT ip from rating 
where ip={$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']} AND section=$section AND name=$name 
then update ELSE INSERT new row
```

is it doable or I better code it in php ?
thank you very much

P.s: I know how to do it with php, I want to learn it with MySQL.

**Also i require that all 3 name,section,ip matchs not only ip**

Comment: You can write a stored procedure to do the job.

Comment: @Chris - replace would work as well, although technically that does either an insert or a delete and an insert rather than an insert or an update.  In his case it may not matter, but if you have triggers or columns with default values it can make a big difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on Eric's excellent answer.

To add a unique constraint on each of the columns ip, name, section run the following code on the database

```
ALTER TABLE `test`.`rating` 
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX `name`(`name`),
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX `section`(`section`),
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX `ip`(`ip`);
```

To run a unique constraint on the combination of columns ip+name+section do:

```
ALTER TABLE `test`.`rating` 
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX `name_section_ip`(`name`, `section`, `ip`);
```

The last thing is probably what you want.

**One last thing**
I'm not 100% sure, but this usage of `{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}` in the query does not look SQL-injection safe.
Consider changing it into:

```
$remote_adr = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$session = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user']);
$query = "INSERT INTO `rating` (`name`, `user`, `rating`, `section`, `ip`)
  VALUES ('$name', '$session', '$rate', '$section','$remote_adr')";
```

Finally putting a ";" in a `mysql_query()` like so `mysql_query("select * from x;");` does not work `mysql_query()` will only ever execute one query and will reject your `;`.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have a unique constraint (`UNIQUE` index or `PRIMARY KEY`) on ip, section and name, you can use this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO `rating` (`name`, `user`, `rating`, `section`, `ip`)
VALUES ('$name', '{$_SESSION['user']}', '$rate', '$section', '{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user = VALUES(user), rating = VALUES(rating);
```

Comment: You should add additional info that the field should be `UNIQUE` index or `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: I didn't saw the unuque clarification first time, thats why I add my comment. You had my up vote and small addition to the solution which I would prefer to use too :)

Comment: @RRStoyanov - Got it, updated my answer as you suggested to clarify.

Comment: Addition to the answer - it might be a good idea to store the IP as integer rather than string (if we're talking about IPV4) due to less space needed to store it / easier indexing / searching.

Comment: thank you but, i want if all 3 matches fields matched not if one of them matched

Comment: @Momen - If you have a unique index on those three fields together (as @Johan describes in the second code sample of his answer), then this will do exactly what you want.