# How can I speed up this query?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I have code to generate four cars from a DB with their photos:

```
$l=$database->query("SELECT car,brand,exactprice FROM $table ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4");
$buffer="";
foreach($l as $l){
    $buffer.="<li><h3>{$l['car']}</h3><p>Price {$l['exactprice']}</p>";
    $k=$database->query("SELECT logo FROM logo WHERE brand='{$l['brand']}'");
    $buffer.="<img src='{$base_addr}/{$k[0]['logo']}'><br>";
}
```

That's my current code. Can I rewrite my MySQL command so I would get `logo` from the `logo` with the first select I did?

Currently it takes 4.32 seconds to load this page.

Comment: -1, SQL-injectable code. You should know about this issue, you have been told before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207763/mysql-insert-if-this-ip-dont-have-any-records

Comment: its not injectable, $database->query does filter and make safe input and output, thanks for head up anywayz

Comment: no it doesn't **only** for values, not for table/column/database names, see my answer and the link in it for details.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me: `$database->query` receives a string, without any hints what it's supposed to mean. If `$l['brand']` == `';DROP TABLE logo; --`, how exactly will $database->query know that `SELECT logo FROM logo WHERE brand=''; DROP TABLE logo; --'` is *not* what you had in mind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't supply what `$table` was, but either way you could use a `JOIN` on the brand column (*assuming that this column is the appropriate foreign key*).

```
SELECT $table.car, $table.brand, $table.exactprice, logo.logo
FROM $table JOIN logo ON $table.brand = logo.brand
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4
```

As far as the performance, you could look into creating indexes on the columns you use frequently and benchmarking by adding `EXPLAIN` in front of the query above.

Some references to check out:

- http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: Good point about benchmarking; but even without specific data, I'd venture to say that calling `RAND()` for every row might be a significant CPU hog.

Comment: @Piskvor , any other ideas about generating randomly 4 rows ?

Comment: @Momen M El Zalabany: [Yes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324983/how-can-i-speed-up-this-query/6325044#6325044)

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT car, $table.brand, exactprice, logo FROM $table JOIN logo ON $table.brand=logo.brand ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4` should do it, by joining the `brand` table into the query.

Comment: Column 'brand' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Did you miss the `$table.` part before `brand` in the field list? It's ambiguous if you don't specify the table because the column `brand` appears in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

Change your script to this:

```
$l=$database->query("SELECT $table.car, logo.logo, $table.exactprice FROM $table join logo on logo.brand= $table.brand ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4");
        $buffer="";
        foreach($l as $l){
            $buffer.="<li><h3>{$l['car']}</h3><p>Price {$l['exactprice']}</p>";
            $buffer.="<img src='{$base_addr}/{$l['logo']}'><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems currently. First, this query should be done [using a JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). The query to do so has already been suplied in other answers, so I won't repeat it again.

Also, in case you're wondering why it's slow, it's also related with the `ORDER BY rand()`. For that, you could check [This Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868102/order-by-rand-alternative)

Answer (score 1):

Please fix the SQL-injection hole by doing:

```
$allowed_tables = array('table1', 'table2');
$table = $_POST['table']; //or wherever table come from.
if (in_array($table, $allowed_tables)) {
    $query = "SELECT car,brand,exactprice FROM `$table` ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4";
    $l=$database->query($query);
    ......
}
```

Using parameters or `mysql_real_escape_string()` will not help you because you are using dynamic table names.
See also this question: [How to prevent SQL injection with dynamic tablenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811834/why-would-this-be-poor-php-code)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your table sizes, indexes and structure, you may have other problems (check with `EXPLAIN SELECT`), but there's a potential issue in `ORDER BY RAND()` - that sorts the whole table, calling `RAND()` for every row, and then throws most of that away and gives you the first four rows; hugely inefficient. You could, however, do a neat trick with subqueries, for example something like [this one from @Jan Kneschke's article](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/):

```
SELECT name
  FROM random JOIN
       (SELECT CEIL(RAND() *
                    (SELECT MAX(id)
                       FROM random)) AS id
        ) AS r2
       USING (id);
```

Note that this will only give you randomly distributed results as long as there aren't any deleted rows (or they are evenly distributed); this may or may not be a problem, depending on the purpose of your query. See that article for an in-depth discussion: http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Comment: Full disclosure: Not affiliated with that site, it simply has a great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT car,brand,exactprice, logo FROM $table left join logo on ($table.brand=logo.brand) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4

Comment: i get this error :( 
Column 'brand' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: that means its in both tables, so you specify which you want in the select